# Dataframe: Get closest DatetimeIndex record from dataframe gives KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got following dataframe `holdings_df`:

```
                                         holdings
2021-06-24 19:59:15.474241+00:00  {'$USD': 10000}
```

I have a general function that should return the holdings of the key that is the closest with a datetime (`current_datetime`) (and not in the future). So a Lower Than or Equal.

I got this working previously by this command:

```
holdings_df.iloc[holdings_df.index.get_loc(pd.to_datetime(current_datetime),method="backfill")]["holdings"],

current_datetime = Timestamp('2021-07-20 00:00:00', freq='B')
```

But this is returning now this error:

```
KeyError: Timestamp('2021-07-20 00:00:00')
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Well, is there a row in your Dataframe that has that date and time in that column?

Comment: No but in my previous code there was either..

Comment: I want to search on the date as a 'give me the first record that is lower than or equal to this date'

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

current_datetime = pd.Timestamp('2021-07-20 00:00:00+00:00')
holdings_df.loc[holdings_df.index <= current_datetime, "holdings"]
```